# Text Object is repeated along with every value of database field in details section

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Am very new to crystal reports. This may seem a simple question for all of you.

I have added a crystal report  file to my asp project in vs 2012 and in details section I added one Text Object and a database field.

This database field belongs to a stored procedure. But in report viewer the text inside TextObject  is repeated along with every value of database field.

[image]

How can I solve this. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you place any field in details (Either database or text field) it repeats for all the records that are retrived from database.. it is the functionality of crystal reports.

If you don't need you can place it in page header or report header that prints once for page and once for report respectively.